# Why is register via useFormContext() not passing values to form state? (react-hook-form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm creating a Date input and trying to pass register into it. I have wrapped the  with <FormComponent {...methods}/> as specified in the docs:

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformcontext

Passing register as a prop works. However, calling `const { register } = useFormContext()` does not propagate the values to the parent's form during submit. Here's (a truncated version of) what I'm working with:

Parent Component:

```
const methods = useForm()

function onSubmit(data) { console.log(data) } // does not return correct dateOfBirth value

<FormProvider {...methods}>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <DateInput
      fieldName={'dateOfBirth'}
      label={'Date of Birth'}
    />
  </form>
</FormProvider>
```

Child Component:

```
export default function DateInput( {fieldName, label, placeholder}:Props ) {

const { register } = useFormContext()

return (
    <div className="date-input-container">
      <label>{label}</label>
      <Input
        {...register(fieldName)}
        type="date"
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I pass register directly, it works as intended.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong, but this stackblitz shows the essence of your code is working as intended: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7enjzv?file=src%2FApp.tsx Post a more complete code sample of what you're working with, try and reproduce it in a stackblitz

Comment: where does the form get `handleSubmit()` function from? Try and change it to `methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)`. EDIT: @AdamJenkins's stackblitz link fixes your problem by applying the changes I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah that works, however it prevented my other fields using the standard method from propagating the values. I appreciate the help; I will dive into this another time but I have a deadline to meet and passing register as a prop works for now. Thank you!